# Does it make sense to remove old entries from my credit report?

Tags: credit-score, credit-history

On my credit report, I have a ton of stuff that ended in 2002, 2003, 2004.  Theoretically speaking, these items should not be on my credit report due to age.  None of these items are negative.

However, previously, I've seen how most innocent looking changes to my financial life caused significant changes to my credit score.

So, I am wondering, is it safe to request removal of these old items?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Equifax FAQ: [How Long Does Information Stay on My Credit Report](http://blog.equifax.com/credit/faq-how-long-does-information-stay-on-my-credit-report/)?- "Good information, like your on-time payment of credit card bills or your mortgage, can stay on your credit history forever. Having more good information helps strengthen your credit history and increase your credit score."

Removing old items for the sake of 'cleaning up' your report may not be possible, and is probably unnecessary. 'Old' items, closed accounts that were paid off, are not a negative, although I understand the desire to see them fall off.